# GetAllNetworkInterfaces() return an incomplete list

Tags: c#, network-programming

NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() doesn't return a complete list,
when I go to A network device, and using properties I disable internet protocol version 4(TCP/IPv4) check box, GetAllNetworkInterfaces stop recognizing the device.
I find this odd as although the device is not internet capable after this(we still may have IPv6 but for the sake of the argument) its still a network device
can someone explain this, or show how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time searching I found that a complete list can be accessed by using the following:

```
        SelectQuery wmiQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searchProcedure = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
        foreach (ManagementObject networkAdapter in searchProcedure.Get())
        {
            //here do whatever you want to do to the adapter
        }
```

A more general description can be found at(not C# specific):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx

Also in C# make sure to reference System.Management, or you wan't be able to use the code above