# C# NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() returns empty list - network interfaces initialization not yet completed?

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-services

I develop an application in C# (.NET 4.6.2) that gets installed as a Windows service by an installer build via WiX 3. The service starts automatically when Windows starts.

On application startup the list of available network interfaces gets loaded via [`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces?view=netframework-4.6.2).
Sometimes, on a computer running Windows 11, the returned list is empty and I cannot figure out the reason.

**My guess (or better hope):** There exists a built-in Windows service that does some kind of network interfaces initialization. And that service startup did not complete before the system started my service. Or my service start is scheduled before the network service start. Both situations would then explain why the returned list of interfaces is empty.

**So my question is:** Does such network service exist and what is the name of the service?

If so, I may be able to register a service dependency directly via WiX functionality and do not need to run, e.g., a custom action that does a call to `sc triggerinfo start/networkon`. But, said that, I am even not sure if `sc triggerinfo` may solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25740102/1025555) yet?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride: Will this work, if the network interfaces are not yet initialized? In addition the question creator describes an other problem.

Comment: I think your real problem is you are forgetting the network interfaces can be added and removed at any time. So you should really be constantly re-checking that list.

Comment: Why don't you just set your service to Automatic Start Delayed? I agree you should be rechecking the list periodically as it could change. Also why do you need it at all? If you want to set up a listener, you should use `0.0.0.0` as the local address, and the system will allocate the correct adapter automatically.

Comment: The app periodically check that list, but at startup it must be complete. Will think about delayed start, thanks. Another workaround may be to drive a loop on startup until the list is available. But the cleanest way would be to use a system trigger when the interfaces really are available.

Comment: I think declaring a service dependency is the cleanest solution. I had the quick look at my windows services and the "Network List Service" seems like a good candidate in your case. [Others use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855290/which-windows-service-ensures-network-connectivity) the "Server" service in similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the start type of my service to manual and adding a start trigger via p/invoke in a custom action.

The trigger does the same as `sc triggerinfo start/networkon`. My service gets started, if network interfaces are ready while booting up the system.

MS DOCS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfig2w